# How can I use encapsulated a structure in asn1c? (using CONTAINING )

Tags: c, asn.1

I would like to use CONTAINING in asn1c (http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/). I don't know how can i give values for the CONTAINING structures.

In my example i would like to give values in the Octasd SEQUENCE for version and tsapolicy. I thought i can do it like any other asn1 types.

Other types for example the INTGER you can use functions to give values.
I can give the contentType value with asn_long2INTEGER function:

```
 EncapsulatedContentInfo_t *encapcontinfo;
 asn_long2INTEGER(&encapcontinfo->contentType, 32);
```

In code for example: EncapsulatedContentInfo->eContent.octasd.version
But i don't "see" behind octasd.

Is there any way to reach an encapsulated structure?

Part of my asn1:

```
EncapsulatedContentInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
  contentType INTEGER,
  eContent [0] IMPLICIT SEQUENCE {
       octasd Octasd
  }
}

Octasd ::= OCTET STRING (CONTAINING SEQUENCE {
   version INTEGER,
   tsapolicy OBJECT IDENTIFIER
} )
```

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Lev Walkin's compiler doesn't appear to support code generation for `CONTAINING` clauses (at least not embedded ones). I'm not very familiar with it, though.

What you might consider doing if you really need to use the `CONTAINING` keyword is to separate the types, e.g.:

```
Octasd ::= OCTET STRING -- (CONTAINING OctasdSeq)

OctasdSeq ::= SEQEUENCE {
   version    INTEGER,
   tsapolicy  OBJECT IDENTIFIER
}
```

This might all you to treat `Octasd` as a simple octet string and pass its bytes (the value bytes, anyway) to the decoder for `OctasdSeq`. I'm guessing this could be a little harder if you were using PER instead of BER/CER/DER because of potential alignment concerns.